# Error showing at spread operator in redux

Tags: redux

> const newState = {...state};
>                             ^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

I am getting the above error when I tried a simple redux program to increment age. 
The piece of code is as follows:

```
const {createStore} = require('redux');
const initialState ={
    age : 21
}
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    const newState = {...state};
    if(action.type === 'ADD')
        newState.age +=1;
    return newState;
}
const store = createStore(myReducer);
store.dispatch({type : 'ADD'})
console.log(store.getState());
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It sounds like it doesn't support ES6 spread syntax.

Comment: See the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) table in MDN.

Comment: You can't use it in IE, Edge, or Safari.

Comment: I was using IE . That's the problem.